# Can something become hot enough that it stops glowing?

Tags: thermodynamics, electromagnetic-radiation, temperature, thermal-radiation, wavelength

So I understand that matter emits EM waves when hot. And that the higher the temperature, the shorter the wavelength, so cooler flames start off orange and the hotter flames reach light blue and white. What I'm wondering is if, hypothetically, you could take that blue-white flame and could make it considerably hotter, would the emitted wavelength reach UV thus making it invisible to the human eye? If so what temperature would need to be reached?

Comment: No, when something gets hotter it [emits more at every wavelength](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/327748/why-dont-wien-displacement-law-curves-cross/). When it gets super hot, most of the power will be coming out in UV but there will still be plenty in the visible spectrum.

Comment: @knzhou sounds like an answer to me

Comment: @knzhou Agree with BioPhysicist.

Comment: Ethan, everything with a temperature (meaning EVERYTHING) radiates electromagnetic energy.  Cold objects radiate in the infrared and hot objects radiate in the visible spectrum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Wien's displacement law](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/wien3.html),
for rising temperatures the maximum of emitted radiation
shifts from infrared to visible, ultaviolet, X-rays, ...

But the maximum of *perceived* light shifts
from red, orange, yellow, white to bluish-white
and then stays there even for infinitely high temperature
(see the point marked with $\infty$ in the image below).

[image]
<sub>(image from [Color temperature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_temperature))</sub>

Comment: OK that makes sense, but your answer raises another question for me, why does emitted light plateau at the light-blueish region and not continue into ultraviolet?

Comment: @Ethan Well, the perceived maximum needs to be in the visible spectrum.
It cannot be in the ultraviolet simply because we cannot see ultraviolet.

Comment: But why does it need to be in the visible spectrum? Visible light is an arbitrary range from a physics perspective, it's just the most abundant wavelength on earth and so it what pur eyes evolved to detect. Why does incandescent light stay within that spectrum?

Comment: @Ethan You need to distinguish between *emitted* light and *perceived* light.
Of course emitted light continues beyond the visible spectrum to ultraviolet and infrared. But perceived light (and this is what determines the color seen by us) is by definition restricted to the visible spectrum.

Comment: @Ethan take a look at the equation for the blackbody spectrum https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-body_radiation if $T\rightarrow \infty$, then the distribution of power is proportional to frequency to the third power. So the "color" of something glowing at infinite temperature will essentially be whatever color corresponds to a distribution of photons where power is proportional to frequency cubed. Also important to note that, as a commenter said in the original post "when something gets hotter it emits more at every wavelength"

Comment: So essentially the simple answer is, it will start to radiate UV and other invisible higher energy wavelengths, but it won't stop radiating the visible wavelengths and so will appear to stop at a blueish glow?

Comment: @Ethan Yes, that's it.

Comment: @Ethan The next comment links to a script that plots blackbody spectra parameterised by frequency. For details see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wien%27s_displacement_law & https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-body_radiation

Comment: https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxVkcGO2jAQhu-W8g4jeohNTYidYMhKkapKVLuHSqhCHBeZYDZuQkIds01Y9d3rENjV-uKZb_75x9Z8gVUpq6yAXSmzYlfvOzByr6XVdRXA6ifwX7p68VAGKfAkmSc8ni08lLtUBIKLcB6y2XISxR4qHGNBtAhFnCwnPPKQ2lyRCDmbCxHFywlLPCR7q2DBWRwl0Zwzzj3koW-6ssrIzHporw6wxetUhGFIHjwE7hS2H1nAGNYwhXyAJyX7odJRVx_YqwNXPobcKdXmJjXOHx9GfekB3q5XEKt_8Hih8JZNP8DR5a9DqDYjMrSXNYVc362nwAS9T4kHReeKmI_zafbMicPtc-R0WLUn3LrAvY_ABNjNb9VblbXFHQXc0ps_ofBi9L7UlWrS0VH-rs3oveGr66j7T-B-MIUOt2kfEXKXBE1e_8UHI48qXZuzomC1LVXqf3_fbXNSmTXno09BtqrZlnKnyibF_g-j_pxVlXWAHy_Elf0nt4-q0bbzySfxttEXlbKAzch_O96Zog==&lang=sage